# how to interpret theorem about polynomial factorization over modulo ring?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, modular-arithmetic, factoring

polynomial $X^n+a_1X^{n-1}+...+a_n \in \Bbb Z_2[X]$ doesn't have linear factors

$\iff a_n(1+\sum a_i) \neq 0$.

How then $f(X)=X+1$ can has no linear factors? Doesn't the condition expands to  $a_n(1+\sum a_i) = 1(1+1) =1\cdot2 =2= 0\pmod 2$  ?

shouldn't it be "**non-trivial linear factors**"?

Comment: Well, in your example, you have $1(1+1) = 1\cdot 0 = 0$, but the condition says $a_n(1 + \sum a_i) \neq 0$.

Comment: $x+1$ is itself a linear factor.

Comment: @DanielFischer so the condition isn't satisfied but it has no linear factors, this is why I ask

Comment: yes, shouldn't it be "non-trivial linear factors"?

Comment: Oh, but it has a linear factor, $X + 1$ is a linear factor. If you want "non-trivial linear factors", you must add a condition $n \geqslant 2$.

Comment: The claim is that that polynomial has no linear factors *if and only if* $a_n(1 + \sum a_i) \neq 0$. In the case of $X+1$, $a_n(1 + \sum a_i) = 1(1+1) = 0$. So you should expect a linear factor. This linear factor is $X+1$. Where's the confusion?

Comment: (What is a "trivial" linear factor anyway? There are only two linear polynomials - $X$ and $X+1$ - and neither satisfies the condition $a_n(1 + \sum a_i) \neq 0$.)

Comment: because next in the book X and X+1 are given as examples of such polynomials with non-linear factors

Comment: @Billy non-trivial is different than polynomial itself

Comment: so it should be non-trivial because X doesn't meet condition and it doesn't have linear factors other than trivial factor X, and same with X+1

Comment: Have you misunderstood the result? You are given a formula - $a_n(1 + \sum a_i)$ - and told that, if it's $0$, then your polynomial has a factor, and if it's not $0$, then it doesn't. There is no need to distinguish between trivial and non-trivial linear factors, because the result is true in both cases. $X+1$ *is* a factor of $X+1$, even if you want to think of it as somehow "trivial".

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain You wrote, "... in the book $X$ and $X+1$ are given as examples of such polynomials with non-linear factors." That's confusing language - having "non-linear" factors is different from "not having linear factors." Either you have a book with some issues, or you aren't posting the exact language from the book.

Comment: yes, my translation wasn't exact, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it shouldn't say "non-trivial." If $a_n=0$ then $X$ is a linear factor. If $a_0+\dots+a_n=0$ then $X+1$ is a linear factor.

If it said non-trivial, then the statement would no longer be true.

This theorem is stated badly, because it is of the form $\lnot P\iff\lnot Q$, which is always equivalent to $P\iff Q$.

In this case, you can state the theorem as:

> Let $f(X)=X^n+\dots +a_n\in\mathbb Z_2[X]$. Then $f(X)$ has a linear factor if and only if $a_n(a_1+\dots+a_n)=0$.

If you stated instead:

> Let $f(X)=X^n+\dots +a_n\in\mathbb Z_2[X]$. Then $f(X)$ has a **non-trivial** linear factor if and only if $a_n(a_0+\dots+a_n)=0$.

In this statement, $P$ is "$f(X)$ has a non-trivial linear factor" and $Q$ is "$a_n(a_0+\dots+a_n)=0$." With $f(X)=X+1$, $P$ is false and $Q$ is true, so $P\iff Q$ is not true.

So your example is exactly *why* the theorem doesn't have the added condition.

Comment: $f(X)=0$ does not satisfy the above, as it's not in the form postulated in the hypothesis (there's no $X^n$ with coefficient $1$). Note that it requires that $a_0=1$.

Comment: Oops, missed that, thanks. But the theorem extends to $f(X)=0$. :) @tomasz

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think you forgot 1 in condition with braces: sum(ai) should be 1+sum(ai) regarding my notation and yours to express f(X), is this correct? I assume you mean a0 stands for X^n coefficient and equals 0 but it isn't clear